# How to have a systemd service programmatically stop its-self? Even if Restart=always is set?

Tags: systemd

How to have a systemd service programmatically stop its-self?  Even if Restart=always is set?  Thus, any exit code returned, the service is restarted?  If my service stops with exit code 0, Restart=always should not be invoked?  How to mimic 'systemctl stop' from within the service its self?

Comment: See `RestartPreventExitStatus=` in `man systemd.service`

Comment: ...or see `Restart=on-failure`